# Implications of deleting from All Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, bulk-delete, audience-builder

Our organization is cleaning up our All Contacts list. I'm wondering - when the contact is deleted form All Contacts, will they also be removed from any auto suppression lists they may be on? I just want to be sure that if we delete a contact from All Contacts that they will not be removed from our auto suppression lists if they are on there.

Will they also be removed from All Subscribers when deleted from All Contacts? I think yes, but wanted to confirm.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete contacts, they will be removed from your all subscribers list on the email. Depending on the evaluation before deleting, you will not be able send to anyone that is being deleted. Ex: If your deletion time takes 7 days,  then you can't send to people being deleted for 7 days.

The contact list will not affect your de. So your suppression list is fine.  Especially if that email is being deleted, because it can't send.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Please see my answer

Comment: Thank you - I just want to be sure that if we remove a contact from All Contacts, that if they are in our AutoSuppression List (due to unsubscribe, spam complaint or hard bounce) that they wouldn't be able to be reintroduced into our Business Unit in error.

Answer (score 1):

Contact Deletion process affects following parts of your account:

- Sendable Data Extensions
- Lists (including suppression lists)
- Tracking data

This means, that even though your contact is removed from auto suppression lists, you will not be able to send to this individual, as any record holding the Contact Key in your account will be gone.

One exception applies to synchronised data extensions, where you must filter the particular contact from being synced from e.g. Service Cloud to Marketing Cloud. If this is not the case, the same contact might be reintroduced to a sendable data extension, from which he/she has been removed. This might result in the same contact receiving your communication again (as contact deletion process has successfully removed the contact key from auto suppression list).

Comment: I see - so when the contact is deleted from All Contacts, they would also be removed from our AutoSuppression lists in Email Admin and therefore could be reintroduced to our Business Unit potentially and emailed in error? I just want to make sure they we are honoring unsubs where applicable. Thanks for your insights!